# Trigger Enter Button on focus on input field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have input field and i want to trigger keyboard enter button when user focus on that input . Is there anyway to do the same in jQuery or javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#some-input').keypress(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $('#my-button').click();
  }
});
```